# Publish file geodatabase to ArcGIS Online using ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, file-geodatabase, arcgis-python-api, hosted-feature-layer

I am reading in the documentation it should be possible to publish a local file geodatabase as a hosted feature layer to ArcGIS Online. I have been trying different things, but that job keeps failing.

I am using the code below:

```
# Publish zipped fgdb to AGOL

fgdb = r"C:\Users\path\to\zipped\geodatabase.gdb.zip"
serviceProp = {}
serviceProp['type'] = 'Feature Service'
serviceProp['url'] = "https://organisation.url.com"

fgdb1 = gis.content.add(item_properties=serviceProp, data = fgdb, folder = "New folder")
fgdb2 = fgdb1.publish(publish_parameters = {'itemID': fgdb1.id}, file_type = 'fileGeodatabase', build_initial_cache=True, overwrite=True)
```

Has anyone been successful doing something similar? The best I can get is a an empty hosted feature layer. The feature service seems to be created but no feature layers are inside, while the local file geodatabase contains 20 layers.

---

[image: error message related to comment above: using 'File Geodatabase' as a file type.]

error message related to comment above: using 'File Geodatabase' as a file type.

Comment: From an old forum post I found, try setting the file_type to `File Geodatabase` (although how you're using `fileGeodatabase` is correct per the official doc

Comment: To troubleshoot further, upload the zipped fGDB directly to arcgis.com using the add item and see if that works. If that doesn't work, its not a code problem, but something inside the fGDB.

Comment: That is already tested and that works. I can upload the fGDB to AGOL with ArcGIS Pro without problems. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Using 'File Geodatabase' as file_type resulted in the error below:

Comment: Please always provide code and error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is close, but there are a few things you're doing wrong with the properties you're passing into each call. Try the below code (specifically updating what you're passing for the properties and not passing in the itemId to the `publish`... the item itself knows which item it is, thus you don't need to give it this).

```
import arcgis
from arcgis.gis import GIS

g = arcgis.gis.GIS("https://www.arcgis.com", "USER", "PASSWORD")

fgdb = r"C:\temp\foo.zip"
serviceProp = {}
serviceProp['type'] = 'File Geodatabase'
serviceProp['itemType'] = "file"
serviceProp['tags'] = "sometag"

pubProps = {}
pubProps["hasStaticData"] = 'true'
pubProps["name"] ="foo"
pubProps["maxRecordCount"] = 2000
pubProps["layerInfo"] = {"capabilities":"Query"}


fgdb1 = g.content.add(item_properties=serviceProp, data = fgdb)
print(fgdb1)
>><Item title:"foo" type:File Geodatabase owner:USER>

fgdb2 = fgdb1.publish(publish_parameters = pubProps, file_type = 'filegeodatabase', overwrite=True)
print(fgdb2)
>><Item title:"foo" type:Feature Layer Collection owner:USER>
```

Comment: This is amazing! For some reason it was not clear publishing needed specific properties as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it answer's your question, please mark it as such.

Comment: I think the biggest problem in your code was trying to supply a URL and the TYPE. The system guessed you were uploading a CSV based on the properties you were sending it. Setting it to File Geodatabase and file are key.

Comment: Well actually, not entirely. As a capability, I specify more than just 'Query'. I also add 'Edit, Sync, etc.'. But it seems these are not all taken into account. That's normal?